# How do I view the raw signature Postman uses when it makes its OAuth requests?

Tags: oauth, digital-signature, postman, oauth-1.0a

I'm using Postman 5.1.3.  I'm trying to connect to an OAuth 1.0a endpoint using Postman's OAuth screen.  How do I view the raw signature that Postman is using to construct its hashed "oauth_signature" param?  I'm filling in a value for

```
consumer_key
consumer_secret
signature_method
timestamp
nonce
version
```

I'm leaving the HTTP method as "GET" and clicking "Send".  Everything goes through fine, but I'm not able to reproduce the behavior in Java, which is why I'm seeking a way to view the raw signature Postman uses when building its request.

Comment: Are you aware of the option to generate the code snippet for you? you still have to use a library to generate the signature though

Answer (score 0):

To generate the signature, postman follow the RFC, there is no point for them to display the steps to generate that, so it is unavailable on display.

[RFC is 5849 section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4) for signature stuff. It is quite explicit.

Comment: SO discourages posting of links in answers b/c links break.  It is better to cut and paste the relevant portion fo the requirement in the answer.